# PrimeNG calendar bug when applying css class from bootstrap

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, primeng, primeng-calendar

I have this strange bug where I use PrimeNG to display a DatePicker in my application. When I try to use bootstrap's `form-control`, I get a visual bug.

Here is my template:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="valeur">Valeur</label>
        <input type="number" id="valeur" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <label for="dateDebut">Date de début</label>
        <p-calendar id="dateDebut" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" styleClass="form-control" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <label for="dateFin">Date de fin</label>
        <p-calendar id="dateFin" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" styleClass="form-control" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the result:

[image]

**EDIT**

If it's of any help, here is the generated HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-5" _ngcontent-scp-1="">
   <label for="dateDebut" _ngcontent-scp-1="">Date de début</label>
   <p-calendar ng-reflect-show-icon="true" ng-reflect-date-format="dd/mm/yy" ng-reflect-style-class="form-control" styleclass="form-control" id="dateDebut" dateformat="dd/mm/yy" _ngcontent-scp-1="">
      <!--template bindings={
         "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
         }-->
      <span ng-reflect-initial-classes="form-control" class="form-control ui-calendar" ng-reflect-raw-class="ui-calendar">
         <input id="dp1467976345328" ng-reflect-value="" class="hasDatepicker ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-left" ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" type="text"><!--template bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
            }--><button ng-reflect-icon="fa-calendar" type="button" pbutton="" class="ui-datepicker-trigger ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-c fa fa-fw fa-calendar"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">ui-button</span></button>
      </span>
      <!--template bindings={
         "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
         }-->
   </p-calendar>
</div>
```

Comment: Possibly Bootstrap's `form-control` has a view styles colliding with PrimeNG's input/form layout?

Comment: I added the generated html

Comment: Its exactly the same problem I reported on PrimeNG forum http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=46579&sid=13c74fc76b0678d9a2440f35866d011c

Comment: Thanks @AJQarshi , maybe it will be adressed (even if they don't seem very active on the forum...)

Comment: @AJQarshi Don't know if you're still having problems with this, just wanted to let you know that I provided solution.

Comment: For info - `Primefaces` calendar component shows similar behavior and works as expected if we apply `form-control` to `inputStyleClass` attribute.

Answer (score 10):

I have used the below workaround, and this is working fine in both IE & Chrome:

```
<p-calendar [inputStyle]="{'width':'55%'}" ...
```

Try it

Comment: Working for me. Thx!

Answer (score 6):

`PrimeNG`'s calendar component has four styling attributes, two for adding inline styles and two for adding style (`css`) classes - `style`, `styleClass`, `inputStyle` and `inputStyleClass`.

- `style` and `styleClass` are used to style the component itself (calendar)
- `inputStyle` and `inputStyleClass` are used to style input field

So, this behaviour is **not a bug**, it's expected behaviour because you are using wrong attribute. If you want to add `form-control` class to `PrimeNG`'s calendar input field, you should use `inputStyleClass` instead of `styleClass` attribute:

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="dateFin">Date de fin</label>
    <p-calendar id="dateFin" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" inputStyleClass="form-control" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
</div>
```

Check entire list of attributes for `PrimeNG`'s calendar component [here](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar).

Comment: Hi Stephan.  Thanks for your anwser.  I tried but unfortunatly it still show a bug, like you can see here: http://i.imgur.com/rkjyel0.png  The code I used is `<div class="form-group"><p-calendar id="dateDebut" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" inputStyleClass="form-control" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar></div>`

Comment: @Shimrod I see, but that's whole another problem caused by `[showIcon]="true"`. Consider using `placeholder` or something instead of it.

Answer (score 3):

1. use "`inputStyleClass`" property to set the css class

> `<p-calendar inputStyleClass="form-control"></p-calendar>`

2. If you are not using Inline form, then override the "`ui-calendar`" css class

> ```
> .ui-calendar {
>     display: block;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Adding this css worked for me to get the icon in place as well as adding form-control to the inputStyleClass attribute.

```
.ui-calendar button {
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.ui-calendar {
    width: 100%;
}

<p-calendar dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" showTime="showTime" hourFormat="24" formControlName="start" [showIcon]="true" inputStyleClass="form-control"></p-calendar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeng 11 / Bootstrap 4.

Adapt CSS:

```
.p-calendar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
}
```

No need for setting `styleClass` on the `p-calendar`:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="dateFin">Date de fin</label>
    <p-calendar inputId="dateFin" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
</div>
```

Comment: it worked kool snippet

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @Srefan Svrkota's answer. You can make another css class that overwrites the form-control class's inline style.

```
    .showCalenderInline
    {
    display: inline !important;
    }

and apply to calendar : inputStyleClass="form-control showCalenderInline"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys maybe you can try this.
im using this for my code

add **styleClass** and **inputStyleClass** like this:

> `<p-calendar styleClass="form-control" inputStyleClass="form-control" ></p-calendar>`

and try to change some css, for me like this :

> `.ui-inputtext{ 
>       margin:-7px -12px; 
>      }`
>
> `.ui-button, button.ui-button.ui-state-default, .ui-button.ui-state-default{ 
>     top:0px;
>     right: -1px; 
>   }`
>
> `.ui-calendar button{ 
>       width: 2.5em; 
>    }`

and the result is
[image]